# how to connect server and client over internet in python

Tags: python, web-services, websocket, client-server

I learned how to connect the client and server using sockets when both of them are on the same wifi. However, when the client computer and server computer are connected to different wifi modems, the client can not find the server. I wonder how should I change my code so that the client becomes able to connect to the server regardless of the wifi network they're connected to?

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '192.168.1.2'
PORT_NUMBER = 5000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
myMessage = "Hello!"
b_myMessage = myMessage.encode()
print(type(b_myMessage))
myMessage1 = "Ended"
i = 0
while i < 10:
    mySocket.sendto(b_myMessage,(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))
    i = i + 1

mySocket.sendto(myMessage1.encode('utf-8'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
```

So that it will connect over TCP, and then port forward port 5000 (or whatever port you're using) on both your PC and your WiFi router.
You'll then need to change the server IP to your server's *Public* IP, rather than the private one, in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I had changed the parameter to SOCK_STREAM as the demo in https://realpython.com/python-sockets/. But I can't get what you mean by putting forward the port on WIFI router.

Comment: @HoOman Google: How to port forward / What is port forwarding

Comment: when I changed the private IP to public IP in server code, it gives an error: the requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: @HoOman Nono, don't change the IP in the server code to the server, whatever is _connecting_ to the server needs the _server's_ IP address, so it knows what to connect to. The server itself should just be responding to whatever connects to it.

Comment: Alright. And putting forward method should be applied to client computer or the server computer?

Comment: So, I should have bought a Static IP in advance?